# I want to call and modify the element that I want to choose in same classes

Tags: javascript, for-loop, classname

I don't know how to call the single or any element in same classes like if p.innerHTML == null then the background of div will change or make any code. The only thing I know is getting a document by ClassName and call the element through [0], [1], [2], [3], ... and so on.. But it mades a lots of codes as the div is many. Is there any code to make the code shorter?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Page title</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="box">
<p class="ppp">Philippines</p>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
<p class="ppp">Singapore</p>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
<p class="ppp">null</p>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
<p class="ppp">Japan</p>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
<p class="ppp">null</p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>

<style>
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
div{
   width: 50%;
   background: blue;
   color: white;
   font-size: 22px;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   margin: 5px 0;
   text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 600px){
body{
   flex-direction: row;
   gap: 10px;
}
div{
   font-size: 30px;
   padding: 15px;
}
}
</style>

<script>
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var b = document.getElementsByClassName("ppp");

if(b[0].innerHTML == "null"){
a[0].style.background = "red";
}
if(b[1].innerHTML == "null"){
a[1].style.background = "red";
}
if(b[2].innerHTML == "null"){
a[2].style.background = "red";
}
if(b[3].innerHTML == "null"){
a[3].style.background = "red";
}
if(b[4].innerHTML == "null"){
a[4].style.background = "red";
}

</script>
```

The code above is perfectly working but there's a lot of code in Javascript. What if I make 20 div? So that the code is extend as the div extend also.

The only problem for this is to make the code shorter. I use

```
for(let i = 0; ppp.length > i; i++){
if(ppp[i].innerHTML == "null"){
this.style.background = "red";
}

}
```

But it's not working....

Comment: Hello guys, I use mobile Phone for now so that I didn't provide Snippet. I hope that there's person edited my code. I appreciate him/her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```js
for(let i = 0; box.length > i; i++){
  if(box[i].innerHTML == "null"){
    box[i].style.background = "red";
  }
}
```

Or you can use a functional programing manner, and make it a function that's has better readability

```js
function highlightNullBoxes(boxes) {
  Array.from(boxes)
    .filter((el) => el.innerHTML === "null")
    .forEach((el) => {
      el.style.background = "red";
    });
}

// You can simply call this 
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
highlightNullBoxes(a);
```

Comment: The code is now working, thank you...

Comment: You are welcome, it would be great if you would like to accept my answer :) thanks :)

Comment: Anyway, I'm wrong. What if the null word is in paragraph tag? Like <div class="box"> <p class="pTag>null</p></div>. How to change the div background if the class pTag.innerHTML is null?